# M.2 SSD somtimes fails to boot/not detected in BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, motherboard, bios

so few days ago my M.2 SSD started showing signs of failure on my ASUS n580VD laptop. It would sometimes fail to boot, and not show up on bios as a boot device. However, the bios can still detect the SSD in the PCIe slot. First, I thought the SSD was failing, so I tried installing another M.2 SSD in the same slot, but it still showed signs of failure. I am starting to think that the PCIe slot is faulty.

Few details:

- ASUS N580VD
- Intel M.2 SSD 600P series
- Samsung V-Nand SSD 970 EVO NVMe M.2
- Tried using Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME and Windows 10

Here is the list of the things I have tried to diagnose the problem:

- memtest
- Removed secondary drive
- Resetting the CMOS battery/BIOS
- Tried booting with different settings in BIOS
- Have used tools to check the health of both of the SSDs. They are both healthy (according to the tools).

Booting from the secondary drive works fine.
I am unsure what else I should try before I can conclude that the slot on the motherboard is faulty. Any feedback/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ran any S.M.A.R.T tools to determine the overall health of the drive?  What is the age of the drive?  What does the Samsung software indicate is the expected lifespan of the drive?  Focus on tools that indicate the health of your SSD instead of your DDR3/DDR4 memory.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that detail in the question. I have used multiple diagnosis tools on both of the SSDs and they are both healthy. The Intel 600P SSD is about 6 months old, and the Samsung SSD is only a few days old.

Comment: Please add that to the detail of the original post by clicking on the grey edit link above and to the left. Also, please be specific in stating which diagnosis tools you ran, how you ran them, and what the results were.

Comment: Please add the S.M.A.R.T. results. Without them the question will probably be closed. Ideally also run a S.M.A.R.T. test.